# How solve c# CS0006 error from a existing project in solution

Tags: c#

I've lost hours trying solve this CS0006 Error, so I could solve doing what following:

- Removing project reference.
- Configuring solution to Debug in Active Solution Configuration and choosing ANY CPU in Active Solution Platform.
- Solving errors in project
- Rebuilding a solution.
- Referencing the Project Again.

**Is there another method to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before that was solved by manually deleting the bin and obj directories, cleaning the solution, and rebuilding.

Comment: I need to delete bin too my dear, I forgot

Comment: Please vote as the answer if this solves your problem 

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, sorry!

Comment: My dear Mark, I saw that a Yellow Exclamation Apearing When a Reference a Parent Project who wasn't builded or has errors